# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

this is setting my varibles and creating the hash I then try to create the users from json objects and hardcode a password but im returned an error. Im getting  a TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
and im not quite sure why the jsonfile does not contain a password and i must hard code one for each user

```
require 'json'
encrypted_password = '#$taawktljasktlw4aaglj'
file = File.read('db/people.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
records = JSON.parse(File.read('db/people.json'))

records.each do |record|
    records['encrypted_password' => encrypted_password]
    user = User.create!(record.except('logins'))
    user.logins.create(record['logins'])
end
```

Comment: `records['encrypted_password' => encrypted_password]` I'm not sure it's correct syntax :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be something like: `record['encrypted_password'] = encrypted_password`

Comment: if i do that i get this active record error, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank Im trying to set this password for every user on creation in the db

Comment: Wouldn't you normally say `record['password'] = 'unencrypted password'` and then let `User` deal with generating the encrypted version? Also note that you want to work with `record` (not `records`) inside the iteration. Or better yet `User.create!(record.except('logins').merge('password' => 'unencrypted password'))`.

Comment: If this is going to be used - you should never use a default password.  Decide if they need one & follow the rails way or use Devise gem like everyone else to handle that aspect.  If you are building your own from scratch for fun, check out Michael Hartl's rails tutorial for better options than what you're doing.

Comment: Your third and fourth lines appear to be relics and can be removed. @Alex, recall 
that `a['b'=>'c']` is the same as `a[{ 'b'=>'c' }]`.

Comment: In terms of how the question is written - you should start out with describing the business use you are trying to accomplish so people can best direct you.

"Hey guys, I'm importing a table of users to the new app" or "just building this for fun & want some test users etc"

Comment: This is not going to be used its a learning experience part of the challenge is to hardcode the password so all users can sign in. It has to be encrypted through devise and and i have to populate the users using the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly setting `encrypted_password`, set `password` and `password_confirmation` instead and let [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) do the job of encryption. This way, your users will get a default password that you set. Your code now should look as follows:

```
require 'json'
password = 'temporary_password'
file = File.read('db/people.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
records = JSON.parse(File.read('db/people.json'))

records.each do |record|
    record['password'] = password
    record['password_confirmation'] = password
    user = User.create!(record.except('logins'))
    user.logins.create(record['logins'])
end
```